# C# Cannot Deserialize Complex Json Object With Array

Tags: c#, json

So I use `HttpClient()` to get Json object from web api. The object contains the list of all provinces in a country.

This code calls the json deserialization:

```
rj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RajaOngkirCity>(response);
```

The response is like this:

```
{
    "rajaongkir": {
        "query": {
            "key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        "status": {
            "code": 200,
            "description": "OK"
        },
        "results": [{
                "province_id": "1",
                "province": "Bali"
            },
            {
                "province_id": "2",
                "province": "Bangka Belitung"
            },
        .....]
    }
}
```

These are my classes:

```
public class RajaOngkirState
{
    [JsonProperty("rajaongkir")]
    public RajaOngkirStateResult RajaOngkir { get; set; }
}

public class RajaOngkirStateResult
{
    [JsonProperty("query")]
    public RajaOngkirStateQuery StateQuery { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public RajaOngkirStateStatus Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public RajaOngkirStateResults Results { get; set; }
}

public class RajaOngkirStateQuery
{
    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }
}

public class RajaOngkirStateStatus
{
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public int Code { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class RajaOngkirStateResults
{
    public List<RajaOngkirStateList> States { get; set; }
}

public class RajaOngkirStateList
{
    [JsonProperty("province_id")]
    public int ProvinceId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("province")]
    public string Province { get; set; }
}
```

It seems that `rajaongkir.results` which causing me the problem.

Here are things I have tried:

1. I tried to change `province_id` type into string, but still error.
2. I tried to change the `List<RajaOngkirStateList> States` into `Dictionary<string, RajaOngkirStateList>` but still error.

The error I am getting:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'ECommerce.ShippingMethod.RajaOngkir.RajaOngkirStateResults' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>   Path 'rajaongkir.results', line 1, position 118.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently your `Results` property claims to be an object *containing* an array - as if your JSON for it looked like this:

```
"results": {
    states: [{
              "province_id": "1",
              "province": "Bali"
            },
            {
              "province_id": "2",
              "province": "Bangka Belitung"
            }
    ]}
```

Instead, the `results` property in the JSON *is* the list.

So all you need to do is remove the `RajaOngkirStateResults` class entirely, and change your `Results` property to:

```
[JsonProperty("results")]
public List<RajaOngkirStateList> Results { get; set; }
```

I'd personally rename `RajaOngkirStateList` to just `RajaOngkirState`, given that it's *not* a list, but that's a separate matter.

Comment: Spot on! I wonder why I could not see that. I know the renaming is not good. Thank you.